# Android studio, calling adapter in adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have an adapter that fills up a listview with textviews read from a json file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXUtY.jpg), now i want to add an autoCompleteTextView to the textviews talked about earlier so its possible to choose possible answers but when i try to add an Arrayadapter (to fill the autocompleteviews) inside my already excisting adapter it wont let me, any ideas how i should do this?

my current (not working) code:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {...}
        else {...}

        holder.editText.setHint(HintArrayList.get(position).getEditTextValue());
        holder.editText.setThreshold(1);


--->    // not possible?
--->    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
--->          (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, MainActivity.OptiesArray); //cannot resolve  constructor 'ArrayAdapter'

        holder.editText.setAdapter(MainActivity.adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already in an adapter, you cant reference `this` as a context,
You can get the context from any view of your parent adapter.

#### Replace

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
    MainActivity.OptiesArray
)
```

#### With

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    holder.editText.getContext(),
    android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
    MainActivity.OptiesArray
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

- XML

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/yourid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorGrayDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
```

- JAVA

```
    holder.editText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourid);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(parent.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,MainActivity.OptiesArray);
            holder.editText.setAdapter(adapter);
```